# How do i pass data get in Jquery function from hyperlink to servlet?

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("inside function");
    $(".month").click(function(e){
         alert("hii");
         $("a").click(function(){
             var m = $(this).attr("id") // or you can use this.id
             alert("current  selected month"+m);
             $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "Controller?action=month",
                    data : m,
                    success : function(data) {
                        alert("sucess");
                    }
              });
         });
     });              
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg1">
    <div class="bg2">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="box">
                <article id="content">   
                    <div class="box1">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="h">
                                <div class="h1">     
                                    <ul class="month">      
                                        <li><a class="month" id="01" href="#">January</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="month" id="02" href="#">February</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="month" id="03" href="#">March</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="month" id="04" href="#">April</a></li>                           
                                        <li><a class="month" id="05" href="#">May</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="month" id="06" href="#">June</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="month" id="07" href="#">July</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="month" id="08" href="#">August</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="month" id="09" href="#">September</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="month" id="10" href="#">October</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="month" id="11"href="#">November</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="month" id="12"href="#">December</a></li>
                                    </ul>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="h2">
                                    <div align="right">
                                        <a href="maintenance_table.tiles" class="button2">Show All</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <center>
                                        <h2>Maintenance Form</h2>
                                        <form id="mentainenceForm" action="#"method="post">

                                            <table>
                                                <tr class="wrapper">
                                                    <td>Date:</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" class="input"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Electric :</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" class="input"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr class="wrapper">
                                                    <td>Water :</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" class="input"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr class="wrapper">
                                                    <td>Internet:</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" class="input"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr class="wrapper">
                                                    <td>Maintenance:</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" class="input"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td><a href="#" class="button2">Submit</a></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </form>
                                    </center>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get month id onclick of hyperlink.i get the id in jquery fuction but after getting id i want  to send that id in my controller to get details .so please suggest me what can i change in my code so that code works fine.

Comment: You can append the month to the URL in your ajax call :)
`url : "Controller?action=month"+"&monthValue="+m,` and get the monthValuein your controller java as request parameter

Comment: i have corrected as you suggest but control not going to Servlet .

Answer (score 0):

You need to first **preventDefault** your code on clicking the a tag.

```
$(".month").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need inner click listener. All click events on elements with class `.month` will be processed.

Your corrected js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("inside function");
    $(".month").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var m = $(this).attr("id") // or you can use this.id
         alert("current  selected month"+m);
         $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "Controller?action=month",
            data : m,
            success : function(data) {
                alert("sucess");
            }
         });
     });
});
```

Comment: i have corrected code.But servlet doesnt call.i have give Controller action in web.xml and getting month by request.getparameter..but not even first system.out.println ("inside servlet"); print on console.

Comment: Well check routing in your app and url in your ajax request.

And if you still need help, update your question with servlet code

Answer (score -1):

You are using Jquery in your code, as for my understanding you have to include the jquery library.  Try this code include in your file then run.

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">